# How to run karate UI tests on any cloud platform

Tags: cross-browser, karate

I have to test web and mobile application and I am using Karate as my automation framework. I want to run my automated tests on any of the cloud platforms like browser stack, lambda test or anything similar.
can any one please help if we can do it and also if there is any demo project for the same.
Thanks in advance.

I checked some videos on how to run cucumber tests on these platforms and karate is some what similar to cucumber except the fact that there is no step definition file where we can define the cloud platform details.

I am not getting any idea where we can define the cloud platform details when we only have feature files in karate.

Comment: please refer to these answers, many teams use saucelabs and it is the same concept for other providers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+saucelabs - it may require more research on your end, my recommendation is try and then next time ask more specific questions